# Make use of an unknown database file?

Tags: database, parsing, file-format

I have some database files I'd like to pull data from (and push to).

The first problem is that I don't know what format the database is in.

Each table (or object) seems to have a separate pair of files, such as `ACCOUNT.FS5` and `ACCOUNT.IDX`. Some of them also have `.SAV` files.

<strike>A friend suggested that they are likely to be [**Flagship**](http://fship.com/) database files, presumably because of the FS5 extension.</strike> **Edit:** this is incorrect, they are not Flagship files, they are database files for the software 'EXACT'.

If this is the case, the second problem is that I don't know how I'd go about querying on these files. I have no schema per se, although the application is capable of exporting the data in csv format. Judging by the unfriendly nature of the csv, I'd imagine it to be pretty closely aligned to the database schema.

Any ideas?

Comment: were you able to so something with those files? I am having same issue, please do reply

Comment: Sorry amitchhajer, I never cracked this one.

Comment: hey @aaaidan we were able to get the data finally from those files into mssql using the tool provided by SOE (which was shitty, had password combo and more stuff), but conclusion, cracked it :D

Comment: We wait with bated breath!

Comment: ah.. sorry! Will do short summary tonight and will elaborate by the weekend

Comment: Have you got a link to your blog post? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @amitchhajer Could you share the tool?

Comment: Hey, I did not use any specific tool. So what happened in my case, used the server where I found these files. They had their own database implementation over oracle/mssql. Also had an server which was random password protected (password being changed every time you login). That server gave me access to the database, after I cracked the password using brute force. Do you have access to the server where these files are being used?

Comment: @amitchhajer. I am in this position also. Can you give some advice on the brute force technique you employed? Is it a long password they use or something simple like a 4 digit PIN. I am wondering if the password is related to the current date time or else how would a user know what it is when it changes? I have seen simple passwords like this employed in similar situations where if the date was May 12 ie 0512, the password would be 5021, ie a simple transposition. I have just tried a lot of these perms trying to access the SQL upsize export but no joy. Any advice you have I'd be grateful for!

Comment: @amitchhajer Are you able to share more about your experience? I think we're all talking about the EXACT database, unless I'm mistaken...

Comment: Also you, @kjack ? Were you ever able to access the data?

Comment: @kjack Sorry I almost missed your comment, my bad. @ aaaidan Yes exact database
So the password was a numeric, but I did not put my brains in finding how are they changing the password. Made a windows application which tries number from 1 to n till it finds the right one, pure brute force technique and it actually worked out

Comment: Great! How did you connect @amitchhajer? Does the server use ODBC or something?

Comment: It had its own application to connect to the database server, not ODBC

Comment: If this Question is still outstanding I'd be willing to help out, I've got a tool created by my company that will export the .FS5 files you're talking about, they're a bespoke database created by Software Of Excellence for the EXACT software.

Comment: Hi @JackTweeddell, that's very interesting! Is this tool proprietary?

Comment: Interested in any tools and techniques to parse EXACT database. @JackTweeddell R4 right?

Comment: Did anyone ever actually figure out how to access the files?

Comment: @JasonH Nope. Let us know how you go. :)

Comment: @aaaidan Well that is disappointing.

Comment: Agreed. I think someone will need to reverse engineer this format, with a copy of the dbms software at hand. Unfortunately, this would be laborious (aka expensive) and I don’t know whether the market is big enough to support this work. The format also probably changes over time, so it’s a treadmill!

Answer (score 0):

If what you think is in these files, is not confidential, I would create the project on one of freelance sites, like "vWorker", and ask for a complete data extraction there.

You can as well specify the destination file format (say, .sqlite) you know how to deal with.

Hope it helped.

Regards